# Sending Form data as Attachment

Tags: forms, attachments, email

on my wordpress site i have a form where users can register to our club. Now the software we are using to handle all the club members allows to import a new member via a csv file. 
Now my thoughts where that pack the form data into a file and send it to myself as an attachment. (The software we are using does not have an API we could use for that)

Is there a way to implement this client side only? Or do i have to do some PHP server side processing (preferably not, i'm not very confident with php)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s going to require at least some server code, otherwise how would the file get to you? Presumably the form is being processed on the server, since as far as I’m aware you can’t send email from client side code.

Comment: It would have to have server-side processing. In order for a file to be attached, your form processing would need to create the file so that it could be attached (server side) and then be emailed (also a server side process).